# Nodejs - Cannot read property 'models' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I´ve inherited a Nodejs/mongodb project, short story the developer left, the webapp was working and is not anymore. So I`m trying to figure out why. I´m a PHP developer making the transition to node, mongo, mongoose, express...you name it, but I´ve just started and help would be really good.

So it lives on a NGINX server, Linux debian 9, node 12, mongo 4, it used to have an ssl certificate but it expired now.

Here´s the link: http://plataforma.drsmile.pe/ - I know it is in spanish.

Just click on "Crear una cuenta"(below) it will show the input fields once filled and trying to submit the error comes up. [login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKAeA.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your routes, you need to find `registro-usuario` service. Which returns that error.

Under that route there should be mongodb service call which uses `variableX.models`. So that means in your code `variableX` is not defined.

Comment: Thanks a lot  that helped me to point out the issue, there was a bad a mongodb connection